# How is cell phone located by server in push email

Tags: server-push

How is a client (cellphone) is located by the server in push email. Does it require an active TCP connection to be maintained by the client ? Does the client need to have a public IP for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cellphone must maintain an open connection to the server - almost all cells are behind one or more layers of NAT gateways, making it impossible for the server to reach out to the client unless the client has opened a connection and kept it open.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So I believe when the client connects to server to check the email in beginning it initiates the TCP session and that is never closed.

Comment: It may be different for Blackberries, as those have their own rather unique email push setup. But in general, for your average phone, yes, no mail notices can go server->client until the client has initiated a connection.